# bigQuery - how to use row values to create columns for a new table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

**I have the following genomic table (over 12K rows) in BigQuery. A long list of the PIK3CA_features (column 2) are related to the same sample_id (column 1)**

```
Row sample_id   PIK3CA_features  
1   hu011C57    chr3_3930069__TGT    
2   hu011C57    chr3_3929921_TC  
3   hu011C57    chr3_3929739_TC  
4   hu011C57    chr3_3929813__T  
5   hu011C57    chr3_3929897_GA  
6   hu011C57    chr3_3929977_TC  
7   hu011C57    chr3_3929783_TC
```

**I would like to generate the following table:**

```
Row sample_id   chr3_3930069__TGT   chr3_3929921_TC chr3_3929739_TC
1   hu011C57    1                   1               0
2   hu011C58    0
```

Meaning, one row for every sample ID and a 1/0 if the PIK3CA_feature exist at this sample.

Any idea how to easily generate this table?

Many thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1):

The only idea that comes to mind is using the concepts of [ARRAYS and STRUCTS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#arrays_and_structs) to get somewhat close to what you need, like so:

```
WITH data AS(
SELECT 'hu011C57' sample_id, 'chr3_3930069__TGT' PIK3CA_features union all
SELECT 'hu011C57', 'chr3_3929921_TC' union all
SELECT 'hu011C57', 'chr3_3929739_TC' union all
SELECT 'hu011C57', 'chr3_3929813__T' union all
SELECT 'hu011C57', 'chr3_3929897_GA' union all  
SELECT 'hu011C57', 'chr3_3929977_TC' union all
SELECT 'hu011C57', 'chr3_3929783_TC' union all
SELECT 'hu011C58', 'chr3_3929783_TC' union all
SELECT 'hu011C58', 'chr3_3929921_TC'
),

all_features AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT PIK3CA_features FROM data
),

aggregated_samples AS(
  SELECT
    sample_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT PIK3CA_features) features
FROM data
GROUP BY sample_id
)

SELECT 
  sample_id,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT PIK3CA_features, PIK3CA_features IN (SELECT feature FROM UNNEST(features) feature) FROM all_features AS present ORDER BY PIK3CA_features) features
FROM aggregated_samples
```

This will return for you one row per `sample_id` and a correspondent array of structs with each feature and its presence in the sample_id.

As BigQuery natively supports this type of data structure maybe you could have this representation for your data without losing any capacity for advanced analyzes such as using analytical functions, subqueries and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by grouping on the sample id.

```
SELECT 
    sample_id,
    COUNTIF(PIK3CA_features = 'chr3_3930069__TGT') as chr3_3930069__TGT,
    COUNTIF(PIK3CA_features = 'chr3_3929921_TC') as chr3_3929921_TC,
    COUNTIF(PIK3CA_features = 'chr3_3929739_TC') as chr3_3929739_TC
FROM [your_table]
GROUP BY sample_id;
```

Assuming you have no duplicate PIK3CA_features per sample id, this should give you what you need.